# Laravel project cloned from GIT not working

Tags: git, laravel, terminal

Everytime I clone a Laravel project ( ex: https://github.com/flytomek/shopping-list) into my XAMPP localhost, I get this strange error:

> Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shopping-list/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shopping-list/artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shopping-list/vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='.:') in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shopping-list/artisan on line 18

I have looked over many similar posts, runned:
**composer install --no-scripts** and I still get the same error.

Firstly I believed it's because of file permissions, I am running macOs and had similar issues with scripts not being able to access files, but I ran  **chmod -R 777 shopping-list** and I get the same issue.

Comment: It's saying a file in the `vendors` directory doesn't exist. Check and see whether it's correct. I think you have done something wrong when installing dependencies with composer. Why are you using `--no-scripts`?

Comment: try `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

1- install composer

2- rename `.env.example` to `.env` and updated it with your database credentials

**Then run this 3 command in your project terminal**

3- `$ php artisan key:generate`

4- `$ composer update`

5- `$ php artisan serve`

From this url you can run this properly.

Answer (score 0):

as noted, most (if not all) laravel projects exclude vendor/ and node_modules/ directores.

check out the contents of the .gitignore in the repo you listed:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
/.vscode
/.vagrant
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
.env
```

so these three steps should get you running:

1. create: .env
2. run: composer install
3. run: npm install